# Scala Enumeration: Choose some values as type

Tags: scala, types, enumeration

Consider the `WeekDays` enumeration:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
    type WeekDay = Value
    val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
```

Now I want to define a variable that can take only weekends as value, something like:

```
val weekend: WeekDay.Sat | WeekDay.Sun
```

But obviously this is not correct Scala syntax. Is there any way I could do or approximate this?

Comment: Please specify what functionality you like to provide for these merged values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just googled "Scala enumerations", and clicked on the [second link](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html). In a nutshell, this quotes Martin Odersky who says that enums are meant as simple integer constants with names and an order. If you want types, you should use case classes. Since weekend days are also weekdays, it sounds as inheritance would be appropriate:

```
sealed trait Weekday
sealed trait WorkDay extends Weekday
case object Monday extends WorkDay

sealed trait WeekendDay extends Weekday
case object Saturday extends WeekendDay
case object Sunday extends WeekendDay


object Main {     
    def onlyWeekendDays(d: WeekendDay) {
        println(d)
    }
    def allDays( d: Weekday ) {}

    def test() {
        onlyWeekendDays( Saturday );
        allDays( Saturday );
        allDays( Monday );
        // this fails to type-check: onlyWeekendDays( Monday );
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to use keyword `new` to create case class

Comment: No-param case classes should be avoided. You should instead use case objects. I also suggest making the trait sealed.

Comment: @noem Thanks, I've modified the example.